# Unexpected results from a macro function

Tags: objective-c, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I defined a macro as follows:

```
#define ccpd(__X__, __Y__) (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ? CGPointMake(__X__ * 0.416667f ,__Y__ * 0.416667f) : CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```

Later:

```
CGPoint p1 = ccpd(1280, 440);
CGPoint p2 = ccpd(1024 + 256, 440);
```

This what I get:

```
(gdb) p p1
$2 = {
  x = 533.333801, 
  y = 183.333481
}
(gdb) p p2
$3 = {
  x = 1130.66675, 
  y = 183.333481
}
```

Why am I getting different results? Am I misunderstanding how a macro works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You macro in the second case expands to something like:

```
CGPointMake( 1024 + 256 * 0.416667f, ...
```

which is

```
CGPointMake( 1024 + (256 * 0.416667f), ...
```

Add parenthesis around the macro parameters:

```
CGPointMake( (__X__) * 0.416667f, (__Y__) * ...
```

or better: make a proper function and let the compiler optimize it.

Comment: What's not clear? Macro expansions are essentially pure text substitutions _before_ the compiler proper sees the code. There's absolutely nothing tricky going on here.